# Enforce Registration of Derived Types

Tags: c++

I have an implementation of a registrar for classes that are derived from a certain base class. The intent is to have each derived class register itself and in the process provide some information about itself, which in the example below is provided through a string.

What I'm missing is a way to force classes that derive from `Base` to register themselves through initializing the static member `reg`. In other words, is it possible to have the compiler somehow produce an error if a derived class doesn't define/initiatlize the static member?

```
struct Registrar {
  Registrar(string type) {
    registry().push_back(type);
  }
  static vector<string> & registry() {
    static vector<string> * derivedTypes = new vector<string>;
    return *derivedTypes;
  }
};

//CRTP
template <typename Derived>
class Base
{
  static Registrar reg;
};

class Derived1 : public Base<Derived1> {/*Class definition*/};
class Derived2 : public Base<Derived2> {/*Class definition*/};
class Derived3 : public Base<Derived3> {/*Class definition*/};
//...

//Initialize the static members of each derived type
//Commenting out any of the following 3 lines doesn't produce an error.
//Ideally, I want it to produce a compile error.
template<> Registrar Base<Derived1>::reg("Derived1");
template<> Registrar Base<Derived2>::reg("Derived2");
template<> Registrar Base<Derived3>::reg("Derived3");

int main() {

  cout << "Registered Types:" << endl;
  for(vector<string>::const_iterator it = Registrar::registry().begin();
      it != Registrar::registry().end(); ++it) {
    cout << *it << endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: best I can think of is a linker error (not compile error), and the only way to do that would be to somehow access `reg` in the `Base` class (say in the constructor) - this should trigger a linker error (with the caveat that you have indeed used the derived type in question somewhere...)

Comment: @Nim: I was thinking exactly the same ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cause a linker error in g++ at least by adding a dummy function to the registrar: `void blah() { }` and then calling it from a dummy constructor in the CRTP base class:

```
public:
    Base() { reg.blah(); }
```

I can't see a more elegant way to solve this problem.